# How to Fix error use join where distinct count in linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want count data in table, and before count i want distinct. I have data in table like this

```
24
31
31
32
32
39
46
46
50
57
```

I want count distinct data.
I try this code but error :

```
(from d in db.ta_kegiatan_renja
 join e in db.ta_peserta_forum_opd_bobot 
     on d.Kd_Ta_Kegiatan_Renja equals e.Kd_Ta_Kegiatan_Renja
 where d.Kd_Urusan == c.Kd_Urusan 
       && d.Kd_Bidang == c.Kd_Bidang 
       && d.Kd_Unit == c.Kd_Unit 
       && d.Kd_Sub == c.Kd_Sub
 select d)
.Distinct()
.Count()
```

and display error :
Unknown column `Project2.Kd_Urusan` in 'where clause'

Comment: That seems like a pretty clear error message.  Is the column `Kd_Urusan` mapped correctly to the database?

Comment: Have not error in mapped, when i delete DISTINCT and just use COUNT query is work

Comment: What is `c` in your query?  You define `d` and `e` with the `from` and `join`, but then use `c` in your `where` clause.  Also if you want to count distinct numbers why aren't you selecting one specific column?  As it is it will attempt to do a distinct on all columns in the  `ta_kegiatan_renja` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a pity you didn't write the classes!

You seem to have an `IQueryable` sequence of `ta_kegiatan_renja` objects, and you assume that every `ta_kegiatan_renja` object has a property `Kd_Urusan`. The error says that a `ta_kegiatan_renja` doesn't have such a property.

The requirement you wrote has nothing to do with the code that you gave us, besides, this code apparently doesn't do what you want. So if you give us the relevant parts of your classes and the requirement, then maybe we can help you more

Comment: FYI - I've edited your answer to remove the sections where you make fun of the author for writing descriptive variable names in a different language.